# inherit meta class keyword arguments

Tags: python, inheritance, metaclass

in Python3.6+ you can provide metaclass keyword arguments in parenthesis of a class: `MyClass(some_arg="foo")` however these kwargs don't seem to be inherited by any children classes:

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, local, **kwargs):
        print(f'{name} got kwargs: {kwargs}')
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, local)


class MyClass(metaclass=MyMeta, arg1="foo"):
    pass


class MySubClass(MyClass):
    pass
```

The expected output would be:

```
MyClass got kwargs: {'arg1': 'foo'}
MySubClass got kwargs: {'arg1': 'foo'}
```

But the actual output is:

```
MyClass got kwargs: {'arg1': 'foo'}
MySubClass got kwargs: {}
```

Is there any way to inherit these kwargs in a subclass?

Comment: The short answer is "no".  Metaclasses and metaclass arguments are just not a generically useful concept.  They are useful for the internals of Python, but not for users.  Just use normal inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Python does not automatically passes these arguments to subclasses of a created class - and that maybe is more useful exactly due to that:
if arguments of a parent class were automatically included when creating a subclass, the first problem that would arise is: how to combine arguments of all superclasses in the childmost class?

Of course, the obvious way would be to traverse the reversed method-resolution order, and simply update the arguments as a dictionary, passing the final value to the child-most class.

However, that is the *exact* behavior one gets with attributes using plain old inheritance - and the user would have no further control on how these arguments are passed down.

By making these arguments available only to the class that is actually being constructed, one gets full control on how they should be used, INCLUDING how to pass them down to subclasses - if you want to have them available in subclasses, simply create them as attributes on the parent classes:

If ou want the semantics to be the same as attribute inheritance, creating one attribute for each keyword argument is the "one obvious way". You might want to add a prefix to them, so they won't clash with other attributes in the subclasses:

```py
prefix = "meta_"
class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, local, **kwargs):
        # code to retrieve arguments from the bases:
        # (N.B. this does not replicate the MRO algorithm)
        for base in reversed(bases):
            for name_ in dir(base):
                if not name_.startswith(prefix):
                    continue
            kwargs[name_[len(prefix):]] = getattr(base, name)

        print(f'{name} got kwargs: {kwargs}')
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
             local[prefix + key] = value
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, local)


class MyClass(metaclass=MyMeta, arg1="foo"):
    pass


class MySubClass(MyClass):
    pass
```

(Keep in mind that `__init_subclass__` in the class get these argments too, and possibly you won't even need a metaclass, depending on the use you want)

And, if you don't need the full inheritance-behavior, you can use a simple dictionary, with a fixed name, in the created classes to take note of all passed arguments in the parents.

And - the above "collect superclasses parameters" code is only needed because I kept the behaviour you put as an example, to have the arguments before calling `type.__new__` - othwerwise you could just fetch the attributes after the class is created, in the final class, and let Python handle the inheritance logic:

```py
prefix = "meta_"
class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, local, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
             local[prefix + key] = value
        cls = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, local)

        for name_ in dir(cls):
            if not name_.startswith(prefix):
                    continue
            print(f'{name} got custom parameter: {name_}: {getattr(cls, name_)}')
      
        return cls


class MyClass(metaclass=MyMeta, arg1="foo"):
    pass


class MySubClass(MyClass):
    pass
```